# Python - Remove lines from output contains one or more substring from a list

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove lines from output that contains in them one of the substrings in my "pattern_list" with python re but keep the output as one string (without those lines).
So , I looked on re library and wrote the following code:

```
patterns_to_remove = ["$",":",">"]
patterns = "|".join(patterns_to_remove)
extra_lines_with_patterns = re.findall('\r\n.*{} \\w*'.format(re.escape(patterns)), str(output))
for extra_line in extra_lines_with_patterns:
    output = str(output).replace(extra_line, "")
return output
```

So if my output is :

```
$a$
:b:
^c^
```

I want the output to be:

```
a
b
c
```

but I get always None in the end , I guess I did something wrong with the re flags.

Comment: You are not escaping the the pattern and pasting the alternations correctly, use `re.findall('\r\n.*(?:{}) \\w*'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, patterns_to_remove))), str(output))`

Comment: Actually, you need no `findall`,  if you remove with regex, use `re.sub`

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why don't you use a LC like `print(''.join([x for x in output if x not in "$:^"]))` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You escaped a part of a regex pattern with `re.escape(patterns)` and all `|` operators turned into literal pipes, `\|`. Also, you did not group them in the pattern when passing through `format` and the pattern looked like `\r\n.* \$|\:|\> \w*`, so it got corrupt (see [Why do ^ and $ not work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41631727/why-do-and-not-work-as-expected/41631755#41631755)).

So you need to

- Escape the `patterns_to_remove` with `"|".join(map(re.escape, patterns_to_remove))`
- Enclose the `{}`  with a `(?:...)`, [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions), i.e. `'\r\n.*(?:{}) \\w*'`

Use

```
re.findall('\r\n.*(?:{}) \\w*'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, patterns_to_remove))), str(output))
```

Or, since you are removing matches, just use `re.sub`:

```
patterns_to_remove = ["$",":",">"]
output = re.sub('\r\n.*(?:{}) \\w*'.format("|".join(map(re.escape, patterns_to_remove))), '', str(output))
```

**NOTE**: `'\r\n.*(?:{}) \\w*'` = `r'\r\n.*(?:{}) \w*'`.